# passing variable to package json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I am using nodejs and in my package json I need to define a test as follows

```
"test:mine": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha \"./tests/**/objectStore.test.ts\" ",
```

Then when I run npm run test it only runs that specific tests for me.
However I am looking to make it more robust by passing a variable as follows:

```
"test:mine": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha \"./tests/**/${variable}\" ",
```

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*package.json*

```
 \"./tests/**/$VARIABLE\
```

node environment

```
VARIABLE='something'
```